# Custom configuration section and app.config

Tags: asp.net, xml, app-config, linq-to-xml, custom-configuration

I have some incoming XML documents, I need to check attributes that are configurable in this coming XML and if the attribute is not there in the XML document being checked add it.

The attributes to be checked will be specified in the app.config file
OrderRequest.orderDetails.orderSummary.testCount, I need to check if the testCount attribute exists under the element OrderRequest. If No add it along with it’s value which is also specified in the app.config

INCOMING XML   -->  Read the attributes  from the app.config which need to be checked in this XML file --> Read the incoming XML using XDocument --> If the attribute  is not there in the incomg XML add it to the XML.

Any ideas how I can go on this.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a series of articles on how to create custom configuration sections, which can be found here: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/CustomConfiguration/default.aspx

Is this a static development task?  What I mean is, are you only testing the testCount attribute, or is this generic to say loop through the element type and check all of its attributes to ensure they are there?

Either way, essentially you have to find an element, get its name, access your custom configuration section and lookup the name, use the GetAttribute method to check for attribute existence, and append a new attribute to the element if not.

HTH.